# strange results when trying to do xpath on multiple elements using python lxml

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I'm getting a strange result on the following code:

```
doc = html.fromstring(page.content)
# result: <Element html at 0x######>
    
product_list = doc.xpath('//div[@data-index]')
# result: a list of 10 <Element html at 0x######>

for product in product_list:
    title = product.xpath('//img/@alt')[0]
    image = product.xpath('//img/@src')[0]
    price = product.xpath('//*[(@id="price")]')[0]
    print(title + '\n' + image + '\n' + price)
```

The title, image & price print duplicated 10 times only the 1st product element even though if I printed "print(product)" inside the loop, it's all different elements.

I've managed to fix it using the following code:

```
 for product in product_list:

    product_html = etree.tostring(product, pretty_print=True, encoding='unicode')
    product_element = html.fromstring(product_html)

    title = product_element.xpath('//img/@alt')[0]
    image = product_element.xpath('//img/@src')[0]
    price = product_element.xpath('//*[(@id="price")]')[0]
    print(title + '\n' + image + '\n' + price)
```

Now the titles, images & prices are correctly printed for the 10 products without duplicated, but I don't know if that is an efficient solution and what is wrong with the 1st code, any ideas?

Comment: In your first code what you missed is a dot, so the right one should be `product.xpath('.//img/@alt')` instead of `product.xpath('//img/@alt')`. Make sure to change the other twos.

Comment: It works, I don't understand how or why, but it works now, thanks.